# Lamson (Python SMTP Server) Error

Tags: python, email, smtp, lamson

I've installed Lamson via easy_install on my webfaction shared hosting. Went to do the '30 Second Introduction' (See http://lamsonproject.org/docs/getting_started.html) but after:

```
[almacmillan@web129 python2.6]$ lamson gen -project mymailserver
```

I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/almacmillan/bin/lamson", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('lamson==1.0', 'lamson')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 448, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1166, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/almacmillan/lib/python2.6/lamson-1.0-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/lamson", line 3, in <module>
    from lamson import args, commands
  File "/home/almacmillan/lib/python2.6/lamson-1.0-py2.6.egg/lamson/commands.py", line 28, in <module>
    from lamson import server, args, utils, mail, routing, queue, encoding
  File "/home/almacmillan/lib/python2.6/lamson-1.0-py2.6.egg/lamson/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from daemon import pidlockfile
  File "/home/almacmillan/lib/python2.6/python_daemon-1.5.5-py2.6.egg/daemon/pidlockfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    class PIDLockFile(LinkFileLock, object):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

I'm a very new programmer. I'd really appreciate some debugging help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a ticket for the problem here: http://support.lamsonproject.org/tktview?name=06d488141d

Use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile/0.8 as 0.9.1's
API changes break python_daemon-1.5.5-py2.5.egg/daemon/pidlockfile.py.
0.9.1 comes with easy_install. So, it's not an issue with lamson.

To solve: remove lockfile 0.9.1 from your Python site-packages
and get 0.8 from the cheese shop instead.